# Create Code Editor Style in html

Tags: html, css, markup

I was wondering how to create Code Editor Style in html page like this one. 
http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/databaseobjects.html

He has different colors for different variables and strings. He used `<pre>` and `<span>` to style but I am not sure if there are faster ways to do this. Any thoughts? Thanks a lot.

Comment: That particular guy seems to have done it by hand with html markup. There are also javascript libraries you can use that will do that all for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used it myself, but Stackoverflow uses [Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) (according to [this question](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/)).  It seems to have been built with only JavaScript and CSS.